# Need advice on how to have a drop down menu that allows to only show certain selected option values when a specific account is selected?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show a specific option within a dropdown menu when only two accounts (Either of them more specifically) is chosen. I can get the option to appear within the dropdown menu but stuck.

I tried some solutions but just cannot seem to get anything to work.

```php
<? $IS_SETTLEMENT = in_array($attributes['zz_account'], array(GetSystemValue('foo', 'foo_inprocess_ZZ'), GetSystemValue('bar', 'bar_inprocess_ZZ'))); ?>

<option value="SD" <? $IS_SETTLEMENT = ($sort_by == 'SD') ? print 'selected' : ''; ?> >Settlement Date</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically populate the drop down with values based on the user from the DB.

SO,

1. Get value(s) that dictate which values the user gets.
2. Write some logic or add a field to your DB to say what the drop down will be.
3. In php, echo the dropdown and values to the screen.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that next then.